# How do I know when a user has reached the end of the text in NSTextView

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

My users are reading readonly text in a `UITextView`.  When they have finished reading a selection, I would like to be able to display a `Completed Reading` button.  How can I detect when the user has scrolled to the end of the text?

Comment: To clarify the confusion - I said NSTextView instead of UITextView - so my question was edited to change the tag from iOS to OSX which resulted in 3 people (most helpfully) providing OSX specific answers...sorry.  Still looking for a iOS solution, please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First before each read calculate the size of the text in the textview based upon the size of its widt. Then from there check if the content offset of the textview has reached the size of the maxSize of the text that was loaded in the text view.

Comment: There was a problem with the tagging on the question.  Mistagged as OSX.  App is for iOS. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This would be the same answer for OSX and iOS your still going to have to read the size of the text and somehow coordinate where you content offset is in comparison to the full size of the UITextViews contentHeight

Comment: When you set the text of a UITextView and the size of the text is greater than its bounds, the contentSize of the UIScrollview that UITextView is built upon is set to a size greater than its bounds. While you are scrolling you can check the contentOffset, this is the property that tells the UIScrollView what frame to show within the UIScrollViews bounds. So since you will calculate the size of the text and gets its height. That height should be equal to the height of the contentOffset + the views bounds.height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float scrollerPosition = [[[textView superview] verticalScroller] floatValue];
```

The scroller position should be between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Comment: I believe the text view's `superview` will be the clip view. Use `-enclosingScrollView` instead, in any case, as it's more reliable.

Comment: Thank you, but there was a problem with the tagging on the question.  Mistagged as OSX.  App is for iOS.  Thanks, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's right to consult the vertical scroller's position. What happens if the scroll view is large to enough to show the whole text view without scrolling? Is the scroller at 0.0 or 1.0?

I think you should consult the scroll view's `-documentVisibleRect` and compare it to the text view's `-bounds`. If the `NSMaxY()` of the former is greater than or equal to the `NSMaxY()` of the latter, then the text view's bottom is visible. If the text view might also scroll horizontally and you care if they scrolled all the way to the right, also check the `NSMaxX()` of both rects in the same way.

Comment: Thank you, but there was a problem with the tagging on the question.  Mistagged as OSX.  App is for iOS.  lol - I tried consulting the scroll view's -documentVisibleRect - really I did.